# XML-BEANS compiled schema: Could not locate compiled schema resource org/apache/poi/schemas/ooxml/system/ooxml/ctstring4cdatype.xsb

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xlsx, xmlbeans

SpringBoot, trying to generate a xlsx file containing pivots, but every time it crash with this stacktrace.

Using xmlbeans 5.0.3

`XML-BEANS compiled schema: Could not locate compiled schema resource org/apache/poi/schemas/ooxml/system/ooxml/ctstring4cdatype.xsb (org.apache.poi.schemas.ooxml.system.ooxml.ctstring4cdatype)`

The line of code is e.addNewS();

```
XSSFPivotCacheDefinition a = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition();
   CTPivotCacheDefinition b = a.getCTPivotCacheDefinition();
   CTCacheFields c = b.getCacheFields();
   CTCacheField d = c.getCacheFieldArray(index);
   CTSharedItems e = d.getSharedItems();
   CTString f = e.addNewS();
   f.setV(value);
```

I divided using chars from a to f because i didn't know which line was.

I noticed that it's trying to connect to this url http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument

I do not know what to do, Im going crazy...

Comment: the "have you tried turning it off and on again?" phrase for POI / XmlBeans is: "have you verified you are running with the correct dependencies and don't have duplicates in the classpath?" ... usually people keep the old schema jar in the dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the @kiwiwings's hint, I managed to get this working by checking all dependencies. Solved this by using: (at 28/01/2022)

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: please remove ooxml-schemas:1.4 and poi-ooxml-schemas:4.1.2 (sigh) ... you can probably remove poi-ooxml-full too, as poi-ooxml-lite comes in via transitive dependency and having both in the classpath is also bad. If you need ooxml-full, then you need to exclude ooxml-lite

Comment: on a second thought, please try to use only poi-ooxml:5.2.0 everything else should come in via transitive dependency

Comment: Actually, poi-ooxml-full solved the problem

Comment: downvoting due to inclusion of poi-ooxml-schemas and ooxml-schemas